# Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T> requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: angular

The error is coming from: node_modules@nguniversal\module-map-ngfactory-loader\src**module-map-loader.module.d.ts** The red line is under the ModuleWithProviders on the final line of code.

Code:

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Google LLC All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */
import { ModuleWithProviders, StaticProvider } from '@angular/core';
import { ModuleMap } from './module-map';
/**
 * Helper function for getting the providers object for the MODULE_MAP
 *
 * @param moduleMap Map to use as a value for MODULE_MAP
 */
export declare function provideModuleMap(moduleMap: ModuleMap): StaticProvider;
/**
 * Module for using a NgModuleFactoryLoader which does not lazy load
 */
export declare class ModuleMapLoaderModule {
    /**
     * Returns a ModuleMapLoaderModule along with a MODULE_MAP
     *
     * @param moduleMap Map to use as a value for MODULE_MAP
     */
    static withMap(moduleMap: ModuleMap): ModuleWithProviders;
}
```

I have added skipLibCheck: true to my tsconfig file to no avail.
Global Angular version is 14.2.8, local version is 12.2.2.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new ASP.NET Web API with Angular project in Visual Studio.
2. Create a component folder with a component.ts and component.html.
3. Build and run the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the issue of one tool fits all. Angular and Web API have nothing to do with each other. I suggest you create a plain Web API project, test it and then create a separate Angular app with the Angular CLI.

You do not specify what Visual Studio and what updates you have. It can be that the template is outdated. Again. My suggestion is to create each project with their own tools. They are, and they should be decoupled anyways.